# SSL Certificate Files and Usage

Tags: ssl, apache2, openssl, certificate

I have a question about certificate files with Apache + OpenSSL.

1. I have generated the following basic certificate files from the server:

   /usr/share/ssl/csr/mydomain.csr.pem
   /usr/share/ssl/private/mydomain.key.pem
2. I have sent the **mydomain.csr.pem** to the CA authority after purchasing Comodo's Positive SSL at

   http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/comodo.aspx
3. It's approved and got three `*.crt` files, which are:

   AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
   PositiveSSLCA2.crt
   mydomain_com.crt
4. Based on the Apache tutor at

   http://www.apache.com/resources/how-to-setup-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache/

looks like I only need to use **mydomain_com.crt** and put it in

```
/usr/share/ssl/certs/mydomain_com.crt
```

1. My question is, what do I have to do with these two files?

   AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
   PositiveSSLCA2.crt

Looks like it's not necessary, then what are these files given to us? If they are used, then when and how?

Comment: They are likely the 2 certs needed to validate the trust chain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/307845/cant-install-ssl-certificate-on-apache

Comment: The tutorials talk about only one file - the domain certificate (.crt) - for the domain. The big certificate sellers (I use GoDaddy) typically have two files - a chain file (another .crt) and the domain certificate. It's really simple to set them up. In an Apache config file, you specify what directory they're in, you put them in that directory, done. I don't know what the third file is. But, I'm sure it comes down to putting the three in the same directory and editing the apache config file to state where they are.

Comment: Also, see here: http://serverfault.com/questions/382633/difference-between-sslcertificatefile-and-sslcertificatechainfile.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to specify the `PositiveSSLCA2.crt` in the Apache configuration. If the HTTP client trusts Comodo, they should already have the root certificate.

I found instructions on [this page](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm) for configuring the intermediate certificate. Basically, you would specify the `PositiveSSLCA2.crt` in your Apache configuraiton as the `SSLCertificateChainFile`. Your client may trust the root CA, but it probably does not know about the intermediate certificate, therefore could not establish trust without it.

The root CA is probably just for your information, but it might be needed if you ever use an HTTP client that requires you to specify it directly, for trust purposes.